# On Ubuntu, I can't build sha3sum

Tags: private-key, compilation, sha3, public-key, keccak

I was following [this article](https://kobl.one/blog/create-full-ethereum-keypair-and-address). When I saw that I've to have this keccak256-sum, I moved to [this](https://github.com/maandree/sha3sum) GitHub repo.

But, when I am building it, it's giving below issue.

```
    $ make
cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wtrampolines -Wfloat-equal -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wno-variadic-macros -Wswitch-default -Wpadded -Wsync-nand -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wcast-align -Wstrict-overflow -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wundef -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wlogical-op -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wvector-operation-performance -Wunsuffixed-float-constants -Wsuggest-attribute=const -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=pure -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wnormalized=nfkc -std=gnu99 -O3 -c -o obj/keccak-224sum.o src/keccak-224sum.c  
In file included from src/keccak-224sum.c:19:0:
src/common.h:24:23: fatal error: argparser.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:87: recipe for target 'obj/keccak-224sum.o' failed
make: *** [obj/keccak-224sum.o] Error 1
```

& even though I cloned and build [this](https://github.com/maandree/argparser) repo.

But, still I'm not able to resolve it. 
is anyone using the keccak256-sum ?

**My aim is to generate & get hold onto the complete key-pair generated for Ethereum. I'm not interested in generating just an address for Ethereum blockchain. If you can refer other node modules, I'm fine with that too.**

Comment: It looks like you might just need to copy the `argparser.h` header file into the `src` directory for `sha3sum`. If you're looking for alternatives, I found this JS library for the SHA-3 / Keccak hash function: https://github.com/emn178/js-sha3

Comment: Ensure you have compiled and installed the dependencies in DEPENDENCIES file. Alternatively there are many projects that generate wallet offline using javascript or python without the requirement for a compilation. For example MyEtherWallet can be used offline.

Comment: Hi Eric. I've already seen the js-sha3. It's not of my use. As i said that, I'm following a blog and in which i need keccak-256sum the way the author have used it. And i tried copying the argparser.h in the src folder of sha3sum too, but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Ismael. If you have used any python project that you can suggest , which will generate key-pair offline and will allow have access to full key pair set, then it'd be great.

Comment: Hi, Guys. The problem was my own mistake somewhere. I tried this afresh & now it's working. and now I'm able to generate the ether addresses for myself. But now, I've some other question related to these key pair generation. How, just by pasting the private keys in MEW, it can calculate public key associated with it? is it just some fixed big prime numbers are getting multiplied, because of which one can calculate the public key, once they have the private key.(may be I shall ask another question for this).

Comment: Please post your own answer, and then ask a new question if you still have.